# How to load data from database in R by different month

Tags: r, for-loop, rodbc

I'm using RODBC package to load data from database in R and doing analysis based on monthly data.

Since the data is pretty huge and I can't just load all the data together,so what I'm thinking is to load the data month by month and use a loop to do the analysis, below is the logic:

```
table <- sqlQuery(channel, 
               " select * from db where date between 'yyyy-mm-dd' and 'yyyy-mm-dd' ##this period is 1 month##
               "
                 , believeNRows=FALSE) 

####run function on table#####
####then load next month data and run function again#####
```

My question is that how to use a loop to load next month data and replace the previous month table, also how to change the year number when the month number reach 12.

Thank you for your help and have a good one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be one way to do it:

```
dates <- seq(as.Date("2010-01-01"), by = "month", length.out = 13)
for (i in 1:(length(dates) -1)) {
  sqlQuery(channel, sprintf("select * from db where date between %s and %s;\n", dates[i],dates[i+1]), believeNRows=FALSE)
}
```

Note a couple of things:
First, the sequence of dates would have to be edited according to your needs, second; the queries go until the second to last element of dates (otherwise you would get a `NA` (so go one month into the future) and third; this will not print the queries that you are sending, if you would like to do so, change (or add), the following command:

```
cat(sprintf("select * from db where date between %s and %s;\n", dates[i],dates[i+1]))
```

In this case, this output (with `sqlQuery` switched for `cat` yields the following (note the simplified loop only for the `SQL` statement, and not the full `sqlQuery` call):

```
dates <- seq(as.Date("2010-01-01"), by = "month", length.out = 13)
for (i in 1:(length(dates) -1)) {
  cat(sprintf("select * from db where date between %s and %s;\n", dates[i],dates[i+1]))
}
#select * from db where date between 2010-01-01 and 2010-02-01;
#select * from db where date between 2010-02-01 and 2010-03-01;
#select * from db where date between 2010-03-01 and 2010-04-01;
#select * from db where date between 2010-04-01 and 2010-05-01;
#select * from db where date between 2010-05-01 and 2010-06-01;
#select * from db where date between 2010-06-01 and 2010-07-01;
#select * from db where date between 2010-07-01 and 2010-08-01;
#select * from db where date between 2010-08-01 and 2010-09-01;
#select * from db where date between 2010-09-01 and 2010-10-01;
#select * from db where date between 2010-10-01 and 2010-11-01;
#select * from db where date between 2010-11-01 and 2010-12-01;
#select * from db where date between 2010-12-01 and 2011-01-01;
```

Comment: Many thanks!  I think it will works.. But I don't understand what the cat is used for, please let me know, thanks

Comment: `cat` is short for concatenate and print (see `?cat`), I added it just in case you wanted to see the queries  you were sending for debugging purposes (or something like that). It is not strictly necessary, the important thing here is the loop and `sprintf`. Without the `cat` you won't be able to see the queries you send (which might be desirable)